# what is the difference between business object, business engine and business entity and business rules

Tags: architecture, business-rules

I was reading an article that refers to the following but did not have any description about what these are actually. Can anyone help me understand these w.r.t software architecture/design? Thank you.

- business objects
- business engines
- business entities
- business rules

Comment: As always, wikipedia is a great place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rule

Answer (score 0):

Business Object and Business Entity are probably the same. They are computer models of things that are important to a business, such as a Sales Order.

A Business Rule is something like this: `if orderQuantity > 10 and customerCountry = USA then discount = 0.10`

Business Engine probably means computer code to validate a business object or to evaluate a business rule, an example being [JBOSS Drools](http://www.drools.org/).